# Running Linux System Calls on Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, assembly

My college syllabus requires me to learn Assembly Programming on Linux.

I own a Macbook Pro, and I'm not really keen on having a dual boot for Linux or installing a virtual machine software like Parallels. And learning the Assembly Language for Mac would be pretty much pointless as it seems quite different.

Is there any way at all by which I can use the exact Assembly Language used on Linux directly in Terminal in my MacBook?

Comment: No, there isn't.  The only way to do it on a Mac are things you are not keen on.

Answer (score 2):

No. OS X and Linux use different [ABIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), which means that assembly language programs are not portable even if you're using the same API on both.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "the assembly language." You can learn the basic elements of the language just fine on a Mac, but the system calls and everything else will be different...

So you basically ruled out the options you have. Go for the emulator I would say. Or a shell account on a Linux machine.